# Letting clients use visual builders plugins/themes on WordPress Multisite installation

Tags: multisite, visual-editor, copyright

I use WordPress Multisite to create and manage my users websites.
I was wondering - Is it possible (and legal by copyright laws) to buy one of those visual builders plugins/themes and **also let my clients use them for their site?**
I know it's possible to use them for building my clients site, but i'm not sure about giving **them** access to the tool.

Comment: You need to specify the actual license of the theme/plugin you are not mentioning...

Comment: There are two, so: GPL and GPL2